# Windows Startup Folder shortcut doesn't run on startup, shortcut doesn't show in Autoruns

Tags: windows-10, boot

Windows 10 x64: v1809

I have five shortcuts in `%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`, and recently I added a shortcut to Resource Monitor; however, it does not run when the system starts, nor appears in Autoruns within the list the other four items are in.

I can open `%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`, click on the Resource Monitor shortcut, and it runs normally.

Comment: Is the Resource Monitor shortcut a hidden file?  While the directory `%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup` can be hidden, all shortcuts within it cannot be, else they will not be launched at startup.  Does the following list the Resource Monitor shortcut: `cmd /c dir "%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"`?

Comment: Yes, all five shortcuts are listed in the directory listing. No special attributes on any of them.

Comment: Task Manager does not start this way either. I think you may need to use Task Scheduler to start these special programs.

Comment: @John, Task Manager is the solution. A bit roundabout, but it does work.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 64-bit.

Move them into the registry.

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run]
"Google Update"="F:\\Users\\somebadhat\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Update\\1.3.33.17\\GoogleUpdateCore.exe"
```

Comment: the registry method did not work (in this particular case - of course it works for many programs)